# How to create a calendar widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know how to create a weekly calendar widget in Flutter like the one shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huRXo.png)

I want to design a weekly calendar widget with the ability to view the next or previous week and customize the color and corner radius of each cell. However, using the DatePicker function does not allow me to customize the cells and arrange them into fixed weekly blocks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e73bi.png)

Here is my code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          DatePicker(
            DateTime.now(),
            height: 100,
            width: 80,
            initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
            selectionColor: Colors.blue,
            selectedTextColor: Colors.white,
            dateTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20
            ),

          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of libraries for weekdays on pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/weekly_date_picker , https://pub.dev/packages/weekday_selector, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_week_view,  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_week , https://pub.dev/packages/weekday_scroller

Comment: If none of them work for you, seems like you'll need to create the whole implementation by yourself.